# le mot anglais "**know**" peut être problématique. Qu'est-ce qu'une paire de mots en français et en anglais qui se ressemblent?

Tags: homonymes

| Le | mot | anglais | "know" | est | "informacion" | en | français | ? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| The | word | English | "know" | is | "information" | in | French | ? |
| La | palabra | ingles | "know" | es | "informacion" | en | Frances | ? |

| Le | mot | anglais | "no" | est | "no" o "non" | en | français |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| The | word | English | "no" | is | "no" o "non" | in | French |
| La | palabra | ingles | "no" | es | "no o "non" | en | Frances |

De plus, "non" est très similaire au mot faux.

Le mot anglais "**know**" peut être problématique. Qu'est-ce qu'une paire de mots en français et en anglais qui se ressemblent?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is asking for a list.  Many words sound the same.  Please rephrase to ask a specific question about homophones.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.